# Change order of randomly selected rows within a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like:

```
c1 c2 c3 c4 result
a  b  c  d  1
b  c  d  a  1
a  e  d  b  1
g  a  f  c  1
```

but I want to randomly select 50% of the rows to swap the order of and also flip the result column from 1 to 0 (as shown below):

```
c1 c2 c3 c4 result
a  b  c  d  1
d  a  b  c  0 (we swapped c3 and c4 with c1 and c2)
a  e  d  b  1
f  c  g  a  0 (we swapped c3 and c4 with c1 and c2)
```

What's the idiomatic way to accomplish this?

Comment: Is it always the same column swapping for all rows that get swapped? (That's far simpler to implement :D)

Comment: @ALollz yes i will always be swapping c1 and c2 with c3 and c4. also will always be changing the last column from 1 to 0 for the rows we randomly selected Edit: added into the OP that I want to select 50% of the rows in the dataframe to make these modifications on

Comment: My best guess so far is that I somehow need to split the dataframe in half, modify 1 and then recombine them? I'm not really seeing any ways to modify only certain rows within a dataframe

Answer (score 1):

You had the general idea. Shuffle the DataFrame and split it in half. Then modify one half and join back.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(410112)

dfs = np.array_split(df.sample(frac=1), 2)  # Shuffle then split in 1/2

# On one half set result to 0 and swap the columns
dfs[1]['result'] = 0   
dfs[1] = dfs[1].rename(columns={'c1': 'c2', 'c2': 'c1', 'c3': 'c4', 'c4': 'c3'})

# Join Back
df = pd.concat(dfs).sort_index()

  c1 c2 c3 c4  result
0  a  b  c  d       1
1  c  b  a  d       0
2  e  a  b  d       0
3  g  a  f  c       1
```

Comment: is the shuffle included in the code you posted? also, wondering if there is a reason you choose a static seed for np.random? I am feeding this data into tensorflow, so should I use a static seed so I can get consistent feedback on the quality of my model?

Comment: @lexxish the shuffle is in `sample(frac=1)`. I just put the seed so that someone could reproduce the example above fully. You can keep it in your code for reproducibility and debugging, but it''s not necessary